# How to merge a branch of a fork to a branch of another fork in github?

Tags: git, github

I know how to compare between forks in Github. However I am running into a problem.

I am trying to merge the `unblock_events_windows_move_resize` branch of [this](https://github.com/mmozeiko/glfw/tree/unblock_events_windows_move_resize) fork of `glfw` into the `resize-move-fix` branch of [my fork](https://github.com/ItsSunnyMonster/glfw/tree/resize-move-fix).

I am not able to find that fork when I am making a new pull request, as seen below:
[image]
So what is the problem here?

Comment: This question is entirely about the *Github UI*, not git itself. The answer for git itself is "check out one branch, add the remote containing the other branch, merge the remote tracking branch", and the concept of "fork" doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know if you are the one who created the original repo and then someone forked it, only they can create a pull request to upstream through the UI. But in terms of opening a PR from one fork to another fork via the web UI, I don't think it's possible (at least at the time of this post).

However, you can easily accomplish what you want via the git CLI tool, assuming both forks are public.

#### Option 1: `git pull`

`git pull` can accept a git URL as an argument. What this means, is you can effectively do `git pull <GIT URL> <branch name>` to merge any public fork into your own. So in this case you would do
`git pull https://github.com/mmozeiko/glfw.git unblock_events_windows_move_resize`.
This is good for one-time or occasional merges. A more permeant option would be to set up a second remote.

#### Option 2: Setting up a second remote

You can add numerous remotes to your local repository. By default, projects' cloned from GitHub will have a remote called `origin` which points to your repository (via the Git URL). You can add a new remote to any repository using `git remote add <short form> <Git URL>`. In your case, this might be something like
`git remote add mmozeiko https://github.com/mmozeiko/glfw.git`. Now you can checkout your branch via `git checkout` and then do `git pull mmozeiko unblock_events_windows_move_resize`.